# How to randomly repaint lines between three different colors

Tags: java, colors, render

I have every part of this program working except for the colors. Right now I have it repainting any random color and I need it to only paint the lines yellow, green, or blue. Can someone lead me in the right direction please?

`package ColoredLines;

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ColoredLines extends JPanel {
    private final Random rand = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Random rand = new Random();

        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);


        for(int i = 10; i < 410; i += 20){
            for(int j = 0; j < 410; j += 410){


                g.setColor(new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256)));
                g.fillRect(i, j, 10, 410);
                }
            }
        }

    }
`
```

Comment: Make an array of those colors and do a random generator to choose between those colors

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I now have the array of 3 colors now how would I randomly call it in my for loop?

Comment: maybe you could do a for loop and mod by 3 and increment by 1

Answer (score 0):

Make an ArrayList of the three colors:
`ArrayList<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();`

Add three colors with: `colors.add(new Color(r,g,b)`

To select a random color using:

`Random rand = new Random();
 Color randomColor = colors[rand.nextInt(2)];`

Note: in rand.nextInt(2); the random number could be 0, so the possible numbers are three (0,1,2).